# Cannot connect to Redis server using Predis?

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, predis, phpredis

I am using Predis PHP library to connect to redis server running on AWS EC2 server. When I try to connect to redis installed on my local system, it works fine. Same code does not work when I try to connect to Redis on AWS EC2. I receive below  error.

```
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. [tcp://my-server-address:6379]
```

I tried to check connect server on redis-cli using below command and it works fine.

```
redis-cli -h my-server-address -p 6379
```

below is the code PHP that I use to connect to Redis.

```
function config() {
        $client = new Predis\Client([
            'scheme' => 'tcp',
            'host' => 'my-server-address',
            'port' => 6379,
            'database' => 1,
        ]);
        return $client;
    }
```

I made sure that there is nothing wrong with my server address.

Comment: Where is your php code hosted?

Comment: @SarwarErfan it is hosted on the same server where Redis is running. By the way, I tried it from Wamp on my localhost as well. Does not work in both cases.

Comment: I am also facing same problem. @AliHamza Have you found any solution?